# What is the best way to submit disabled inputs as part of a jQuery Ajax request?

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty complex form that provides real-time validation and feedback to the user using it as they type in data. Parts of the form may be disabled due to form "business logic" of the inputs, but the server side needs to know the value of these disabled inputs to do some of its checking in the Ajax requests.

I was using jQuery to serialize the entire form, $(form).serialize(), and sending all of this data to the server during my Ajax requests, but this serialized data will be missing any inputs that are disabled. So what is the best way to include all of the form data (even disabled inputs) with each Ajax request?

My current thought is to attach a function to ajaxStart (callback) that would create a client side hash-map of all form inputs' disabled attribute, enable all the inputs, serialize, and then set each form's disabled attribute back to its original value. But this seems overly complex, and I wanted something simpler that wouldn't be as brittle.

Comment: Hmm... is it a must marking them as disabled? Setting them as readonly won't work at all?

Comment: I don't believe the readonly attribute works on select lists.

Comment: @Hannele this question was asked in 2009, the other in 2011, how is this a dupe of that?

Comment: @mido I tried to pick the one that had a better answer I suppose

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try doing something like this to serialize the form:

```
   $(function() {
      $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
          var form = $('form').serialize();
          $('input[disabled]').each( function() {
              form = form + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
          });

      });
   });
```

Test HTML

```
<form action="/action">
   <input type='text' disabled='disabled' value='hey' id='hey' name='hey' />
   <input type='text' value='ho' id='ho' name='ho' />
   <input type='text' value="hi" id='hi' name='hi' />
   <input type='button' value="Serialize" />
</form>
```

Output

```
ho=ho&hi=hi&hey=hey
```

Comment: If there are no other fields then disabled this`form = form + '&' + this.id + '=' + $(this).val();` will give you string in form `&arg=val&arg2=val2&..`, which isn't very nice. You should check first, if form is not empty.

Comment: @gruszczy -- good point.  If, after the form is serialized, `form` is empty, you could add `form = &dummy=nothing`.  It's a pretty rare case though so I'll leave the code sample the way it is.

Comment: It seems like this would fail if the values contain `&`.

Comment: Use the escape function to handle values with &'s:
`... + '=' + escape($(this).val());`

Answer (score 7):

> Parts of the form may be disabled due to form "business logic" of the inputs

You can use "readonly" attribute to disable those input fields. Do like this:

```
<input type="text" readOnly="readOnly" />
```

> The readonly attribute specifies that an input field should be read-only.
>   A read-only field cannot be modified. However, a user can tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it.

from: [HTML input readonly Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

A read-only field also can be submitted to server as query string.

Comment: This seems to work ok on true input tags, but not on select lists.

Answer (score 5):

If your server accepts JSON, you can create a JSON object with jQuery (use jQuery select statements to include the necessary input tags), then send it to the server as an object - more information here: http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/.

Basically, do something like this:

```
var formInputs = { };

$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
  formInputs[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well another option is to simply add a **hidden field** with the value you wan't posted to the server.

Remember to use a **different** (dummy) id for the tag that you disable to avoid any conflict.

Answer (score 1):

To send the disabled value to the backend using .serilize() through a form submit using jQuery to Ajax, it is:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submid").click(function() { // loginForm is submitted
                    $('#ayyappa').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "urls",
                        data:{
                            "sel_opt": $("#ayyappa").attr("value"),
                        }

                    }); // Ajax
                    $("#Number").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }); // Click
            });
        </script>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <input type='text' id="ayyappa"  name='ayyappa' value="ayyappa" disabled>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```