# JQuery sends empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I dont get it... I reviewed my code hundred times and I dont get the error...

I am actually testing a bit with JQuery and AJAX and made a simple form with a textarea to submit. Without AJAX it works fine, but with, it sends always an empty value of my textarea...

The Javascript Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#formPost input").attr("disabled", false);

        $("#formPost input:submit").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'post.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#formPost').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#formPost input").attr("disabled", true);
                    $("#formPost .ajaxloader").show();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var message = $("#flashMessage");

                    message.text(data.msg);
                    if(data.error) {
                        message.addClass("fail");
                    }
                    else {
                        message.addClass("success");
                    }
                    message.show();
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#formPost .ajaxloader').hide();
                    $('#flashMessage').removeClass().
                        addClass('fail').text('There was an error.').show();
                },
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#formPost input").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#formPost .ajaxloader").hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
      <h1>Add new post</h1>
      <div id="flashMessage"></div>
      <form id="formPost" method="post" action="post.php">
        <textarea id="post" name="post"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <div class="ajaxloader">
          <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I use Firebug and look under "Network" -> "XHR" -> "Post" and under Source he shows **post=**

So where is the value gone?

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/zayU5/ . Are you using rich text editor to replace textarea?

Comment: Yes I do lol :/ Is that a bad sign?

Edit: Ok, I removed the CKEditor (Rich Text Editor) and it works fine. But why doesnt it work with the RTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related with CKEditor (as you said in the comment), because WYSIWYG editors replace the appearance of `textarea` and update value on form submit. So you have to use built-in functions of CKEditor for updating `textarea`'s value manually as you are using Ajax. I can't help you specifically with CKEditor but this thread may help: [CKEditor, AJAX Save](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1956967/656489) .

Answer (score 0):

You are disabling the form elements in the `beforeSend` method, but JQuery's `serialize` will ignore those disabled elements. Try removing that first to test. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849693/what-is-the-best-way-to-submit-disabled-inputs-as-part-of-a-jquery-ajax-request) has some ways to get around it.

Comment: I think he is disabling `input` only, not `textarea`.